# Unusual usage of にしては?

Tags: grammar

I have a problem understanding this usage of にしては:

> ファンをないがしろ**にしては**、芸能人**として**やっていけない。

I understand にしては to mean **For A, B** - such as **For** the high price of this meal, it isn't tasty at all (高いにしてはまずい). B comes as a surprise, given A.

But it doesn't make sense to say **For** (the way) he ignores his fans, **as** (として) an artiste/performer he cannot do such a thing.
B is **not** a surprise to the first half of the sentence, A.

Is there another usage of にしては I am missing?

Comment: `Is there another usage of にしては I am missing?`  Yes.

Comment: 「走ってはいけません！」の「ては」とか・・・

Answer (score 1):

The ～にしては construction you mentioned has nothing to do with this sentence.

Simply, [ないがしろにする](http://eow.alc.co.jp/search?q=%E3%81%AA%E3%81%84%E3%81%8C%E3%81%97%E3%82%8D%E3%81%AB%E3%81%99%E3%82%8B) is a set phrase that means "ignore ～", "to make light of ～", etc. `te-form + は` is a way to say "if ～", which is commonly found in the "～してはいけない" construction. [やっていく](http://jisho.org/word/%E3%82%84%E3%81%A3%E3%81%A6%E8%A1%8C%E3%81%8F) here is "to get by" or "to make a living."

> ファンをないがしろにしては、芸能人としてやっていけない。
>   One cannot make a living as a 芸能人 if they make light of their fans.